# Date Value Code For Conversion To Date in PHP or RUBY

Tags: php, ruby, csv, type-conversion

How do I convert a date value to a date in a csv file using PHP or Ruby?

Here is a sample of my column 'created_at' :
created_at
1309380645
1237178109
1303585711
1231175716
 That is the current date and I need mm/dd/yyyy format.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It will help you craft better questions, which (hopefully) will help produce better answers.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide any code, so I won't either.

With Ruby, you'll need [`Time.at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-c-at) to create a Time object from a UNIX time and [`Time.strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) to convert it to the right format.

Comment: In the `%m/%d/%Y` format.

Comment: Yes. It's mentioned in the doc, and I wanted to write a lazy answer for a lazy question.

Comment: Although a quick Google "ruby date format" might lead to the right page today, it's amusing how often it can circle back to questions like this very one. Just adding that for posterity.

Comment: I often google the terms of a 15 minutes old SO question, and I'm surprised to see it in the results already!